# Adding a loss term that enforces sparsity on weights

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lasso-regression

I was wondering if there is a way in TensorFlow to add a loss term that enforces sparsity of the weights in a specific dense layer.

I want to find solution in which as many of the weights in some layer are zeros (similarly to the Lasso method for regression). Is there an easy way to add a norm term on the matrix of weights for a dense layer?

Thanks a lot,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's really straightforward, tensowflow.keras.layers.Dense object has a property of "kernel_regularizer". And you can feed it with any matrix norm.